# Convert hex to ascii in C

Tags: c

I am trying to convert hex (that is a string) to ascii characters. I have written the following function to accomplish this:

```
void Str2Hex(char strIn[],char strOut[], size_t strLen)
{
    uint8_t c[3] = {0};
    for(uint16_t i = 1; i < strLen; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            c[0] = strIn[i-1];
            c[1] = strIn[i];
            c[2] = '\n';
            for(uint16_t j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                sprintf(strOut[(i/2)-1],"%s",c[j]);
            }
            c[0] = '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I am extracting every 2 elements from the input string and storing them in a temporary array `c`, in addition to a null character that will terminate the string. Following this, I am adding them to the output string. Finally, I am clearing the temporary array. I am running this on an STM32 dev board and using UART3 to print to the terminal. My main function looks like this:

```
char    hexbuffer[] = "4D4F4E";
char    charbuffer[100] = {0};

Str2Hex(hexbuffer,charbuffer, strlen(hexbuffer));

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, charbuffer, strlen(charbuffer), 1000);
```

When I try running the above code, nothing is printed to the terminal. I have also tried using pointers in the function, to no avail (also given my knowledge of pointers isn't the best):

```
void Str2Hex(char *strIn,char *strOut, size_t strLen)
{
    uint8_t c[3] = {0};
    for(uint16_t i = 1; i < strLen; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            c[0] = &strIn[i-1];
            c[1] = &strIn[i];
            c[2] = '\n';
            for(uint16_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                sprintf(strOut[(i/2)-1],"%s",c[j]);
            }
            c[0] = '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

A string that would be inputted is "4D4F4E". The expected output would be a string "MON".

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need 4 bytes for `"xy\n"`: one for the x, one for the y, one for the newline, and one for the `'\0'`

Comment: `'\n'` is not the `NUL` character. The zero terminator character is `'\0'`

Comment: If you want to step through an array by 2 elements, use `i += 2` rather than checking whether the current element is odd.

Comment: `c[j]` is a `char`. `%s` is for printing a string.

Comment: What is the actual result you're trying to get? Because your code is just copying characters from one array to another, it's not doing any conversion.

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to convert the every 2 characters of the string (the array "hexbuffer") that has the hex characters, to ascii characters, and store them in another array "charbuffer".

Comment: And which part of your code do you think performs that conversion?

Comment: @Barmar The line of code that uses sprintf, converting every 2 characters from the hex string to characters.

Comment: Your question is as clear as mud. Maybe give us some expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Input string: "4D4F4E". Excluding the "0x" preceding every 2 characters, after conversion, I expect "MON", as in the characters that you would use to abbreviate "Monday" . With my current code, nothing is printed.

Comment: @S23  If a deficiency in the question is pointed out in a comment, fix it by editing the question for all to see without having to wade through the comments.  Improving the question in that way will make it less likely to attract down-votes.  That said some people appear to down vote for poor code, which seems rather miss the point of SO.

Comment: OK, the "using pointers" code is semantically identical.  You cannot pass arrays by value, they were always pointers.  That square bracket syntax is little more than a _comment_ to indicate the intent of a _"pointer to a sequence of `char`"_, rather than _"pointer to  a single `char`"_ - still a pointer and generates identical code.  That was never going to resolve the _semantic logic_ problem of your algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

To be honest, the code is so far from plausible, that I am going to ignore that question and the code and just present a solution.

```
// Convert single Hex digit to integer 0-15
int HexNibbleToInt( char nibble )
{
    return nibble > '9' ? 
           nibble - 'A' + 10 : 
           nibble - '0' ;
}

// Convert string of ASCII hex digit pairs representing 
// character codes to character string.
size_t StrToHex( const char strIn[], char strOut[] )
{
    int i = 0 ;
    for( i = 0; strIn[i * 2] != 0; i++)    
    {
        strOut[i] = HexNibbleToInt( strIn[i * 2] ) << 4 |
                    HexNibbleToInt( strIn[i * 2 + 1] ) ;
    }
    strOut[i] = 0 ;
    
    return i;
}
```

Note that I have omitted the `strLen` parameter.  If it is a pre-condition that the `strIn` is a null terminated string with an even number of characters, then  then you do not need to calculate the length.  Since `strlen()` has to iterate the string to find the NUL and you have to iterate the string in any case, it serves no purpose.  Of course a malformed string that is not capitalised hex digit pairs will have undefined behaviour.  That is easy to handle, but if the string has already been validated you might not want to spend CPU cycles doing it twice.

Note also that I have returned the length of the output which saves yet another unnecessary and potentially expensive call to `strlen()`:

```
size_t output_len = StrToHex( hexbuffer, charbuffer ) ; 
HAL_UART_Transmit( &huart3, charbuffer, output_len, 1000);
```

Moreover as this appears to be targeted at embedded code, I have avoided "expensive" functions such as `sprintf()` and `strtoul()`.  If you are using them extensively already in the code, then there is probably little marginal cost in using them, but the initial cost of invoking them once may be rather high.

Comment: Demo at https://onlinegdb.com/pvp-X43cq

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to parse the hex. `sprintf()` doesn't do any parsing. You can use `strtol()` to parse a numeric string in a particular base.

You don't need to use `sprintf()` to write a single character to an array, just assign the value directly to the array element.

You need to make `c` a null-terminated string, so add `'\0'` to it, not `'\n'`. You don't actually need to append this explicitly, since you initialized the array to all zeroes.

Finally, you need to add a null terminator to `strOut`.

```
void Str2Hex(char strIn[],char strOut[], size_t strLen)
{
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < strLen; i += 2)
    {
        uint8_t c[3] = {0};
        c[0] = strIn[i];
        c[1] = strIn[i+1];
        long ascii = strtoul(c, NULL, 16);
        strOut[i/2] = ascii;
    }
    strOut[strLen/2] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `sprintf()` may be prohibitively expensive given this appears to be for embedded systems code.  But the downvote remains a mystery to me.

Comment: You're right, it's unnecessary. I changed it to a simple assignment.